# Tor and macOS Sierra

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, support, mac

I am an irregular user of Tor but like to have it at hand and use it from time to time. Up until recently, I would update frequently and it all worked smoothly. However, today is the first time I try launching it after upgrading to macOS Sierra and I am bumping into an error for the first time.

Instead of connecting like it used to, the "Tor Status" window stays in place for a while and eventually delivers an error message saying "Tor Launcher. Could not connect to Tor control port".

I upgraded to the most recent version of Tor Browser (6.0.2), created an exception in my Firewall and even deactivated my firewall for a bit, but all to no avail. Is this something someone else has bumped into? All the messages I found seemed linked to other parameters that do not apply to me. Could it be Sierra? Could it be some other functionality that blows ports? Any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This kind of inconveniences are expected when using a very early beta OS. Report the situation to the Tor team.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Rui. I was fearing it could be as simple as that... However, I see no link on the Tor website to report such issues. Am I missing something?

EDIT: I guess the tor-talk mailing list is the closest thing (tor-talk@lists.torproject.org)

Answer (score 2):

If you're having trouble saving the changes to the prefs.js file, might be a permissions issue. Did you try updating the pref.js file using terminal:

`sudo nano ~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/Browser/*.default/prefs.js`

Add

`user_pref("extensions.torlauncher.control_port_use_socket", false);`

and Crtl-O to save, Ctrl-X to exit

(new user so not enough reputation to add as comment to Gbla Kbla's answer so have repeated details here)

Answer (score 0):

After official release i've met the same problem too.
As described [here](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/20215), temporary fix is:
add line

```
user_pref("extensions.torlauncher.control_port_use_socket", false);
```

in ~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/Browser/*.default/prefs.js

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Gbla Kbla. Unfortuntely, this didn't quite work for me. I did add the line but to no avail. When I launch TorBrowser, a window says "Waiting for TorBrowser to start" and invariably an error message says "Could not connect to Tor control port". When I check the prefs.js file, the extra line has disappeared.
PS: I am now running macOS Sierra 10.12.1 public beta 3 and TorBrowser 6.5a3 (though I also tried with the 6.0.5 stable release).

Comment: Anyone? Any help appreciated.